# Exception thread in main

Tags: java, exception, singleton, program-entry-point

I'm trying to create a fabrique design pattern that create one instance (I'm combining singleton with factory designs patterns).

When arriving at main method I can't run and it shows that:

main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ExceptionCreation {
    Animal animal1 = FabriqueAnimal.getAnimal("chat");
    Animal animal2 = FabriqueAnimal.getAnimal("chien");
    Animal animal3 = FabriqueAnimal.getAnimal("cheval");

    System.out.println(animal1);
    System.out.println(animal2);
    System.out.println(animal3);

}
```

factory animal class :

```
public static Animal getAnimal(String typeAnimal) throws ExceptionCreation {

    if (typeAnimal.equals("chat")) {
        Chat x = Chat.getInstanceChat();
        return x;
    } else if (typeAnimal.equals("chien")) {
        Chien y = Chien.getInstanceChien();
        return y;
    }
    throw new ExceptionCreation("Impossible de créer un "+typeAnimal);
}
```

the problem is that :

```
Exception in thread "main" chatChien.exception.ExceptionCreation
    at chatChien.FabriqueAnimal.getAnimal(FabriqueAnimal.java:16)
    at chatChien.Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

Comment: In your factory method you do not have the `if` statement for `cheval` animal. So `ExceptionCreation` is being thrown.

Comment: Yes thats it, but Instead of throwing it and display ' impossible de créer un "cheval" it doesnt run and it shows that -> Exception in thread "main" chatChien.exception.ExceptionCreation at chatChien.FabriqueAnimal.getAnimal(FabriqueAnimal.java:16) at chatChien.Main.main(Main.java:8)

Comment: Beacuse you are not catching it and you let it to be thrown outside of the `main` method. Please read about `try-catch-finally` keywords.